# Command works directly in Powershell but doesn't work when executed through a linux system using powershell

Tags: powershell

In a windows machine, if I open `powershell` and write this command, it works fine.

`powershell -command "&{$p='It works'; echo $p}"`

This outputs `It works` as intended.

But if I **ssh** into the same windows machine using a linux machine and try to execute this command, this gives me an error.

The command:

`/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe -command "&{$p='It works'; echo $p}"`

When I execute this, the following error appears:

```
=It works : The term '=It works' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:3
+ &{='It works'; echo }
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (=It works:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


cmdlet Write-Output at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
InputObject[0]:
```

I have searched a lot but couldn't find the reason behind it. I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me regarding this.

Comment: Remove the ampersand `&`

Comment: As an aside: Note that there's no reason to use `& { ... }` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-command` (`-c`) parameter - just use `...` directly. Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected. /cc @AbrahamZinala

Comment: On th Linux host, is the executable `powershell` or `pwsh`?

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the `$`. Like this:

```
xxx@xxxxx:~$ pwsh -c "&{\$p='It works'; echo \$p}"
It works
```

Adding the example from [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0), executing `&` a scriptblock `{ }` (for this specific case) is not needed at all to which character escaping wouldn't be needed either:

```
xxx@xxxxx:~$ pwsh -c '$p="It works"; echo $p'
It works
```